# RecyclerView ItemTouchHelper Action Drag Ended

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gesture, gesturedetector

I need to listen to the user when he stops drag and drop on my RecyclerView (when he **drops** the selected item).

Can I get this Information through my ItemTouchHelper?

Thanks for helping

Mark: At the moment i only now when the user still moves the item :)

```
@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder source, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    if (source.getItemViewType() != target.getItemViewType()) {
        return false;
    }
    // Notify the adapter of the move
    mAdapter.onItemMove(source.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**UPDATED**

First you can define where an object can be dropped by implementing `canDropOver`

```
@Override
public boolean canDropOver(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder current, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    return current.getItemViewType() == getItemViewType();
}
```

Update your adapter you want to use `onMove` this can be called multiple during a drag operation

```
@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    adapter.moveItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
    return true;
}
```

To detect when an interaction with an element is over implement `clearView` this is for any action type (drag or swipe) in the even that it succeeds (item moved or swiped) or is canceled (item not moved or swiped)

```
@Override
public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
    // Action finished
}
```

Comment: added my onMove method but how can i achieve the information that the move stopped? it only notifies when it s still moving

Comment: @keytomake I updated my answer to include more info. Basically use `onMove` to update you adapter and `clearView` to determine when the drag is completed.

Comment: The clearView is a good place to put viewHolder.card.isDragged = false

Answer (score 5):

You can override **onSelectedChange** in your implementation of **ItemTouchHelper.Callback()**, such as:

```
 override fun onSelectedChanged(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, actionState: Int) {
        super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState)
        when (actionState) {
            ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG ->
                Log.d("DragTest","Start to drag: $actionState")
            ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE ->
                Log.d("DragTest","Start to swipe: $actionState")
            ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE -> {
                Log.d("DragTest","End action: $actionState")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `viewHolder` is always null!

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution using onSelectedChanged. Using drag flag reacts only on drag and not swipe.

```
new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {


           boolean drag = false;


           @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
               
                // YOUR onMove
                return false;
            }


            @Override
            public void onSelectedChanged(@Nullable RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
                super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState);

                if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG) {
                    drag = true;
                    Log.d("DragTest","DRAGGGING start");                   
                }
                if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE && drag) {
                    Log.d("DragTest","DRAGGGING stop");
                    drag= false;
                }
             }

            
        }).attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```