# RecyclerView ItemTouchHelper Action Drag Started

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I've got `RecyclerView` with attached `ItemTouchHelper`, which I construct with

```
class ItemTouchHelperCallback(
        private val adapter: ItemTouchHelperAdapter
) : ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {
    override fun isLongPressDragEnabled(): Boolean {
        return true
    }
    ...
}
```

I am going to call vibration on every drag event **start**. In exact drag start moment.

To do it, inside `ViewHolder` I set `touch listener`. Then I tried to call vibration for the first `ACTION_MOVE` event. Unfortunately, it happens faster than item drag is possible. I want vibration and possibility to move items happen at the same time. To give user accurate haptic feedback, that he is able to drag and move items from now on.

I expected `ItemTouchHelper` or `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` to expose appropriate API. It doesn't.  But I noticed that inside `ItemTouchHelper` there's `mActionState` with value `ACTION_STATE_DRAG`  at the expected moment (inside `onLongPress()` So those 2 classes should know when drag starts! It's a pity they don't share their knowledge publicly.

Also, I've noticed very [similar topic about action drag ended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425494/recyclerview-itemtouchhelper-action-drag-ended) but I couldn't find solution to `action drag started` there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this method to your callback

```
  override fun onSelectedChanged(viewHolder: ViewHolder?, actionState: Int) {
      super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState)

        if (actionState == ACTION_STATE_DRAG) {
            //  your code here 
        }
  }
```

This works well for me

Answer (score 1):

I found hacky solution in the end, which is part of `ItemTouchHelper.Callback()`. `getMovementFlags` is called in almost the same moment like change `mActionState` to `ACTION_STATE_DRAG`. Inside `onLongPress() of` ItemTouchHelper`.

Called twice, so watch out for that ;-)

Tested on `compileSdkVersion = 28`

I'd like to see better solution though.

Comment: I added a better solution even earlier. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65916807/12793676